# Fetching Firebase Data in an AngularFire callback

Tags: angularjs, callback, firebase, angularfire

Every example I have ever seen of an Angular app with Firebase has had a very static path.

Click Add -> Takes you to a New View

Click Save -> Saves Data and Routes you to a list view

Click on Item (from list view) -> Routes you to edit view of that object using $routeparams

I'm trying to write a function that adds a new object to a fb collection **AND** route's the user to an edit view of that particular object and in one action. AngularFire's add() method takes a callback, if I could get the $id for the object that was just added in that callback I could use $routeparams to perform the desired action.

Is this even possible?

*Update: I'm using the AngularFire method .add() which turns out was [modified](https://github.com/firebase/angularFire/pull/26#issuecomment-19065964) to return the new data reference. How is this data actually access though?

e.g. `$scope.object.add(localObject);`

Comment: You can do `var ref = $scope.object.add(localObject)` and extract the name via `ref.name()`.

Answer (score 2):

if you use push(), name() will give you the id generated by FB.

```
var ref = new Firebase('https://<yourfb>.firebaseio.com/somepath');
var name = ref.push($scope.currentObject).name();
$location.path('/somepath/' + name);
```

Comment: Yeah I mean I see that in the API (https://www.firebase.com/docs/javascript/datasnapshot/name.html) and that makes sense, but I'm using the AngularFire method .add() (http://angularfire.com/source.html), which returns the reference after the method runs since this update (https://github.com/firebase/angularFire/pull/26#issuecomment-19065964). At this point I don't see a way to access the returned data reference.